# Static member cannot be accessed with an instance reference, qualify it with a type name instead

Tags: c#, enums

I've looked around for answers to this but I haven't found any that I have been able to use to help fix my problem.
When trying to set the state of a torch in c# from an enum, I get the error message;

> Static member `TorchManager.torch.TurnedOff' cannot be accessed with an instance reference, qualify it with a type name instead

I have tried serializing the enum and using static variables for the enum reference but nothing seems to work.

Here's my code;

```
public class TorchManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    enum torch
    {
        TurnedOff,
        TurnedOn,
        Flickering,
        Resetting
    }

    torch torchState;

    float torchTimer = 0.0f;

    float torchTimerMax = 180.0f;

    float torchFlickerTimer = 00f;

    float flickerRate = 0.1f;

    private float startIntensity = 1.0f;

    float maxFlickerIntensity = 1.8f;

    bool useBatteries = true;

    int batteryCount = 2;

    int batteryValue = 1;


    void Start ()
    {
        startIntensity = GetComponent<Light>().intensity;
        torchState = torch.TurnedOff;
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        CheckForInputs();
        RunFlashlight();
    }

    void CheckForInputs()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
        {
            if(torchState == torchState.TurnedOff && batteryCount > 0)
            {
                torchState = torch.TurnedOn;
            }
            else if(torchState == torchState.TurnedOn || torchState == torch.Flickering)
            {
                torchState = torch.TurnedOff;
            }
        }

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.B) && batteryCount > 0)
        {
            if(useBatteries)
            {
                batteryCount -= 1;
            }
            torchTimer = 0.0f;
            torchState = torch.Resetting;
        }
    }

    void RunFlashlight()
    {
        switch (torchState)
        {
        case torch.TurnedOff :
            GetComponent<Light>().enabled = false;
            torchFlickerTimer = 0f;
            break;

        case torch.TurnedOn :
            GetComponent<Light>().enabled = true;
            torchTimer += Time.deltaTime;
            if(torchTimer >= torchTimerMax)
            {
                torchState = torch.Flickering;
                torchTimer = 0.0f;
            }
            break;

        case torch.Flickering :
            torchFlickerTimer += Time.deltaTime;
            torchTimer += Time.deltaTime;
            if(torchTimer > flickerRate)
            {
                float lightIntensity = Random.Range(0.0f,maxFlickerIntensity);
                GetComponent<Light>().intensity = lightIntensity;
                torchTimer = 0.0f;
            }
            if(torchFlickerTimer >= 15f)
            {
                torchState = torch.TurnedOff;
            }
            break;

        case torch.Resetting :
            torchTimer += Time.deltaTime;
            if(torchTimer > 0.75f)
            {
                GetComponent<Light>().intensity = startIntensity;
                torchTimer = 0.0f;
                torchState = torch.TurnedOn;
            }else if(torchTimer > 0.55f)
            {
                GetComponent<Light>().intensity = 0.0f;
            }else if(torchTimer > 0.35f)
            {
                GetComponent<Light>().intensity = startIntensity;
            }else if(torchTimer > 0.15f)
            {
                GetComponent<Light>().intensity = 0.0f;
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        GUI.Box(new Rect(20, 120, 125, 25), "Batteries in torch: " + batteryCount);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of torchState.TurnedOff
simply use torch.TurnedOff

like in

```
if(torchState == torchState.TurnedOff && batteryCount > 0)
{
    torchState = torch.TurnedOn;
}
```

change `torchState == torchState.TurnedOff` to `torchState == torch.TurnedOff`